# Javascript Gauge control in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, justgage

I'm trying to implement Gauge control with below code **but not getting any output** though when i try the same in html file, i get the output with 3 gauge's.

I changed to `$(document).ready()` instead of `window.onload` as mentioned in the link [window.onload Not Working correclty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054152/window-onload-not-working-correclty). But it didn't help.

I'm beginner on Javascripts or JQuery. Please let me know how to achieve this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
      body {
        text-align: center;
      }

      #g1, #g2, #g3 {
        width:200px; height:160px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 1em;
      }

      p {
        display: block;
        width: 450px;
        margin: 2em auto;
        text-align: left;
      }
    </style>
   <script src="raphael.2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="justgage.1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var g1, g2, g3;

        window.onload = function () {
            var g1 = new JustGage({
                id: "g1",
                value: getRandomInt(350, 980),
                min: 350,
                max: 980,
                title: "Lone Ranger",
                label: "miles traveled"
            });

            var g2 = new JustGage({
                id: "g2",
                value: 32,
                min: 50,
                max: 100,
                title: "Empty Tank",
                label: ""
            });

            var g3 = new JustGage({
                id: "g3",
                value: 120,
                min: 50,
                max: 100,
                title: "Meltdown",
                label: ""
            });

            setInterval(function () {
                g1.refresh(getRandomInt(350, 980));
                g2.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 49));
                g3.refresh(getRandomInt(101, 200));
            }, 2500);
        };
    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="g1"></div>
    <div id="g2"></div>
    <div id="g3"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try jqChart's gauges - http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges

They have lots of examples and rich functionality.

Disclaimer: I work for jqChart.

Best, Maxim Milev